# Java exception error for parpool in matlab

Tags: java, macos, matlab, parallel-processing

I try to run parpool on my macbook pro from 2013 with matlab 2014a. I get the following error:

```
Error using parpool (line 99)

Java exception occurred:
java.net.UnknownHostException: **********: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1473)

......
```

I have tried the two solutions from this http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/139968-parpool-java-exception-occurred-2014a-mac-only-when-wifi-at-home-turned-on

Turning off wifi or editing the hosts-file does not help.

Comment: When you type `!hostname` in the command window In Matlab, it returns a string. In `/etc/hosts` (OS X/Linux), you should add: `127.0.0.1   str` (str being whatever string `!hostname` returned).  Is this what you tried? I had the same issue and it worked for me. (in my case I added `127.0.0.1   server` because my hostname is server)

Answer (score 0):

A patch has been released for this bug see: [Bug report 1119179](http://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/search_results?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search_executed=1&keyword=1119179&release_filter=Exists%20in&release=251&selected_products=&commit=Search)